# asp.net autocomplete fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I need to autocomplete a form's textboxes based on the input of the first text box.

Basically you enter a name in the first text box, that is searched in a SQL table and if found, the remaining text boxes are filled with the relevant information.

I did come across the ajax control toolkit AutoCompleteExtender but that only seems to work for one text box.

How can I auto populate the remaining text boxes? Is there a way to do that with the AutoCompleteExtender?

Comment: Share your `aspx/ascx` code

Comment: The AutoCompleteExtender will only search for items entered into the textbox and find matching results. You should look at using Javascript Ajax to do this, it will be more efficient and you will be able to handle almost every aspect of it.

Comment: Any tips on where to begin with that Nunners?